# Which usage is correct? "in online" or "online"?

Tags: word-usage

My blog topic is "How to find the right freelancer in online"? I would like to confirm whether "in online" or "online" is correct? please help me urgent!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Online](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/online)** is an adjective and adverb, not a noun. So, no need for a preposition before it.

> "How to find the right freelancer online"? is the correct sentence.